# SQLAlchemy RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, recursion, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I currently am stumped as to why I'm gettign the recursion error from the title with the code down below. This error only comes up if either of the for loops are hit (under if ops and if compliance) before the call to results = results.all().

```
@main.route('/search_results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def search_results():
    """ Here we make the search request and then display the results.  We bring in
    the params via the url, then use whooshalchemy to search fields we marked
    with __searchable__ in the model.  If advanced search is selected, we then filter
    the results before we display.  Note that there are two separate searches for the
    separate data types. """
    subject = request.args.get('subject')
    search_type = request.args.get('search_type')
    acct_no = request.args.get('acct_no')
    id_ = request.args.get('id_')
    rep = request.args.get('rep')
    ops = request.args.get('ops')
    compliance = request.args.get('compliance')
    results = []

    ...

    else:
        results = db.session.query(Envelope)
        if subject is not None and subject is not '':
            results = results.filter(Envelope.subject.like('%'+subject+'%'))
        if acct_no is not None and acct_no is not '':
            results = results.filter_by(acct_no=acct_no)
        if id_ is not None and id_ is not None:
            id_ = int(id_)
            results = results.filter_by(envelope_id=id_)
        if rep is not None and rep is not '' :
            results = results.filter_by(initiator=rep)
        if ops is not None and ops is not '':
            ops_name = external_db.get_fullname_from_username(ops)
            for result in results:
                if db.session.query(Envelope_recipient).filter_by(envelope_id=result.envelope_id,role='Operations',name=ops_name).first() == None:
                    results = results.filter(Envelope.envelope_id != result.envelope_id)
        if compliance is not None and compliance is not '':
            compliance_name = external_db.get_fullname_from_username(ops)
            for result in results:
                if db.session.query(Envelope_recipient).filter_by(envelope_id=result.envelope_id,role='Compliance',name=compliance_name).first() == None:
                    results = results.filter(Envelope.envelope_id != result.envelope_id)

    #results.all() is a list of all esignature.models.Envelope or .Process_item objects
    results = results.all()

    return render_template('search_results.html', subject=subject,
                        search_type=search_type, acct_no=acct_no,
                        id_=id_, rep=rep, ops=ops,
                        compliance=compliance, results=results)
```

Oddly enough, the code for some reason works with one name, but no others. If you need any other information, I'm happy to supply it, thank you!

Comment: You seem to be looping over `results` and modifying `results` within the loop.  I'm not certain that this causes the error you're getting, but it isn't very efficient.  A better approach might be to loop over `results` and collect the ids that you want to filter out in a list, then do something like `results = results.filter(not_(Envelope.envelope_id.in_(list_of_unwanted_ids)))` (you may have to import `not_` from sqlalchemy).

Comment: That actually solved it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looping over results and modifying results within the loop. I'm not certain that this causes the error you're getting, but it isn't very efficient. A better approach might be to loop over results and collect the ids that you want to filter out in a list, then do something like

```py
from sqlalchemy import not_
...
results = db.session.query(Envelope).filter(not_(Envelope.envelope_id.in_(list_of_unwanted_ids)))
```